# The server stops working if I wrap express.static in a function

Tags: node.js, express

the code below works:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/public', express.static("./public"));
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

But if I change the `app.use` like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path  = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use('/public', function(){express.static("./public")}); 
// browser error "cannot GET /
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Why? The server doesn't seem to catch any errors

Comment: Why *wouldn't* making a random change alter the behaviour?

Comment: This is because express.static returns a function which is then gets invoked by app.use. In your case your own function gets invoked by app.use thus express.status never gets executed. Invoke your function inside app.use and everything will work like normal. `app.use('/public', (function() { return express.static("./public") })() );`

Answer (score 2):

`express.static()` returns a middleware function when you call it.  You have to pass that specific returned function to `app.use()`.  You don't just call `express.static()` on every request.  You call it once, get the returned function and register that as middleware and `app.use()` will then call that middleware function on every request.

---

When you do it the correct way like this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static("./public"));
```

It's like doing this:

```
const fn = express.static("./public");
app.use('/public', fn);
```

or even like this:

```
const fn = express.static("./public");
app.use('/public', function(req, res, next) {
    fn(req, res, next);
});
```

Hopefully you can see that this code:

```
app.use('/public', function(){express.static("./public")});
```

does not do the same thing as any of the correct solutions.  This calls `express.static()` in every request and never calls the returned function that does the actual work for a given request.

---

Think of `express.static("./public")` like a factory function.  It creates a middleware function that you then pass to `app.use()` or call yourself with `req`, `res` and `next` as the arguments.

> Why? The server doesn't seem to catch any errors

Executing `app.use('/public', function(){express.static("./public")});` is not what you want, but it also doesn't create an error.  All it does is create a new middleware function (which you ignore) on every single request.  It also never calls `next` to let any other request handlers handle the request so your server would get stuck on every request, but it never actually causes a visible error.

It essentially becomes functionally equivalent to this:

```
app.use('/public', function(req, res, next) {
   // do nothing, just causes the request to get stuck since
   // the request is not handled (no response is sent)
   // and next is never called
});
```

The request is never handled and never calls next to advance to other route handlers so the request just gets stuck and will eventually time out.

Comment: @igorcheclakov - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community here at stackoverflow by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to "accept" this answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure.  If not, please explain what you still don't understand so we can further clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './public'), { maxAge: '1d' }));
```